# How do I set a variable to value using React-Redux on the initial page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-redux, properties

I am creating a language switcher for my application. So far, I can support 4 languages (English [en], Spanish [sp], French [fr], and Arabic [ar]). I have already converted all of the language properties files to JSON and I can import those files into my .jsx file. However, when it comes to setting the language, I am running into issues.

For Example:
I have this line of code: `<h1>{messages.en["user.userprofile"]}</h1>`
This translates to **User Profile** in English. If I switch the language to French `<h1>{messages.fr["user.userprofile"]}</h1>`, I will get: **Profil d'utilisateur**.

Instead of hardcoding the language, I am trying to get it to change dynamically. I am using Redux to load the user profile.

```
  const defaultLanguage = useSelector(
    (state) => state.profileReducer.profile.language || []
  );

  ...

  <h1>{messages[defaultLanguage]["user.userprofile"]}</h1>
```

I want to get the `defaultLanguage` on page load. For instance, if the user's language is English, `defaultLanguage` will be set to `en`. However when I do this, I get a white screen and this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user.userprofile')
    at UserProfileNew (UserProfileNew.jsx?e01f:146)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js?61bb:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?61bb:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?61bb:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?61bb:22707)
```

However, if I comment the `h1` tag out and and put `console.log` for `defaultLanguage`, I notice that it prints 5 times. On the first 2 times, `defaultLanguage` is set to `[]`. Then on the last 3 times, `defaultLangauge` is set to the user's language value loaded from Redux. How can I get this initialized on page load so that it won't be undefined? Am I missing something or do I need to change how I write `defaultLanguage` in the `h1` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your problem is not in Redux.

When you are trying to get value from `messages.en["user.userprofile"]` you suppose that you getting value from `messages.en.user.userprofile` but no, it doesn't work this way - JS considers it as getting value from an object by key `user.userprofile` and object structure for JS is

```
{
'messages': {
    'en': {
      'user.userprofile': {
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The most simple an cheapest solution for you problem is using method `get` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/), or any other similar utility library. Thus you'll be able to write

```
get(messages.en, 'user.userprofile', [])
```

and be sure to get values by composed key.